# Can't load waypoints and routes on Google Maps api v3

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I want to display multiple directions with dragable waypoints and save each waypoints.

On my project I can click on the map to create the routes, generating a wayA point and a wayB point and draw a route between them. So, I can make multiple routes.
I can also save them on the database.
The problem is load this points on the map again fetching them on the database and drawing all on the map.

I have two pages, on [index.htm](http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/test.html) you can draw your routes and save them, and on [loady.htm](http://www.inventoresdegaragem.com/dbteste/loady.htm) you can load them on the map.

I tried somethings but without sucess, I will post my try here.

This is my resumed index.htm

```
 var map, ren, ser;
 var data = {};    
 var wayA = [];
 var wayB = [];
 var directionResult = [];

function goma() <---Initialize
{


google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        if (wayA.length == wayB.length) {
        wayA.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,      
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map

        }));
        } else {
        wayB.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      draggable: true,  
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map

        }));  
    ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true} );
    ren.setMap(map);
    ren.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  
    ser.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].getPosition(), 'destination':  wayB[wayB.length-1].getPosition(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK') {
                    directionResult.push(res);
                    ren.setDirections(res); 
                } else {
                    directionResult.push(null);
                }   })      
} }); }  

function save_waypoints()
{
    var w=[],wp;
    var rleg = ren.directions.routes[0].legs[0];
    data.start = {'lat': rleg.start_location.lat(), 'lng':rleg.start_location.lng()}
    data.end = {'lat': rleg.end_location.lat(), 'lng':rleg.end_location.lng()}
    var wp = rleg.via_waypoints 
    for(var i=0;i<wp.length;i++)w[i] = [wp[i].lat(),wp[i].lng()]    
    data.waypoints = w;   
    var str = JSON.stringify(data)   
    var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    jax.open('POST','process.php');
    jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    jax.send('command=save&inventoresdegara='+str)
    jax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(jax.readyState==4) {
        if(jax.responseText.indexOf('bien')+1)alert('Mapa Atualizado !');
        else alert(jax.responseText)        
    }}  
 }
```

This is the resumed loady.htm with my try

```
var map, ren, ser;
var data = {};
var wayA = [];
var wayB = [];
var directionResult = [];

 function goma() {

ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true} );
    ren.setMap(map);
    ren.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    fetchdata();

    function setroute(os)
{
    var wp = [];
    for(var i=0;i<os.waypoints.length;i++)
        wp[i] = {'location': new google.maps.LatLng(os.waypoints[i][0], os.waypoints[i][3]),'stopover':false }
  ser.route({ 'origin': wayA[wayA.length-1].setPosition(), 'destination':  wayB[wayB.length-1].setPosition(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK') {
                    directionResult.push(res);
                    ren.setDirections(res); 
                } else {
                    directionResult.push(null);
                }    
 });
}
function fetchdata()
{
    var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    jax.open('POST','process.php');
    jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    jax.send('command=fetch')
    jax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(jax.readyState==4) {        
        try { setroute( eval('(' + jax.responseText + ')') ); } 
        catch(e){ alert(e); }

    }}    

 }
```

This is my php file:

```
<?   
    if($_REQUEST['command']=='save')
    {

        $query = "insert into inventoresdegara set value='$data'";
        if(mysql_query($query))die('bien');
        die(mysql_error());                 
    }  
    if($_REQUEST['command']=='fetch')
    {
        //$query = "select value from inventoresdegara";
        $query = "SELECT value FROM inventoresdegara";
        if(!($res = mysql_query($query)));      
        $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res,1);
        die($rs['value']);      
    }
?>
```

This is a image from my database to you know how the information are saved
[image]

The only thing that I need to do is load this values to the map, please help me =).

Thanks !

After my try, the loady.htm was this on ser.routes

```
ser.route({'origin':new google.maps.LatLng(os.start.lat,os.start.lng),
    'destination':new google.maps.LatLng(os.end.lat,os.end.lng),
    'waypoints': wp,

    'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK')ren.setDirections(res);
}
```

Comment: Can you filter out the "noisy" code? You might get a better response if you only post what's relevant.

Comment: Edited, filtered the max possible, who need my full script can acess on each page link and use CTRL+U for source code.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason to saving waypoints is to reproduce the route they came from, you're better off saving the entire route and then showing it on the map without re-requesting the route again. See [Displaying results of google direction web service without using javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450061/displaying-results-of-google-direction-web-service-without-using-javascript-api/38244681#38244681)

Otherwise, if you just want to get a fresh route from A to B through waypoints, your current approach of calling ser.route() with them is correct.